# Differential Backups in SQL Server 2008; Able to restore through SSMS but unable to restore through Transact SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-backups, database-restore

I am facing an issue while restoring the databases from differential backups. Here are the steps I performed

```
DROP DATABASE DBName_delta
GO
BACKUP DATABASE DBName TO DISK = 'E:\Fullbak1.bak' 
GO
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'E:\Fullbak.bak'
GO
RESTORE DATABASE DBName_delta  
    FROM  DISK='E:\Fullbak.bak' 
   WITH MOVE 'DBName_Data' TO 'E:\DBData\DBName_delta.mdf',   
   MOVE 'DBName_Image_Data' TO 'E:\DBData\DBName_delta_Image_Data.mdf',   
   MOVE 'DBName_Log' TO 'D:\DBLog\DBName_delta.ldf',
   NORECOVERY

--Made Some changes in the database
BACKUP DATABASE DBName
   TO DISK = 'E:\DiffBak1.TRN'
   WITH DIFFERENTIAL
GO

--Made Some more changes in the database    
BACKUP DATABASE DBName
   TO DISK = 'E:\DiffBak2.TRN'
   WITH DIFFERENTIAL
GO

RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'E:\DiffBak1.TRN'
GO

RESTORE LOG DBName_delta FROM DISK='E:\DiffBak1.TRN' WITH NORECOVERY
GO
```

> Msg 4305, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   The log in this backup set begins at LSN 81125000000059600297, which is too recent to apply to the database. An earlier log backup that includes LSN 81121000000116200001 can be restored.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   RESTORE LOG is terminating abnormally.

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'E:\DiffBak2.TRN'
GO
RESTORE LOG DBName_delta FROM DISK='E:\DiffBak2.TRN' WITH STANDBY = 'c:\undo.ldf'
GO
```

But when I tried to restore the same E:\DiffBak1.TRN through SSMS by using the WITH NORECOVERY option, it restored the database and again I was able to perform the restore of the same file using the Transact SQL. Am I missing something here? Is this something to do with the RESTORE DATABASE? I am sure that we are not missing any of the logs in between. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to figure this out. As I mentioned, I was able to restore the differential database through the SSMS wizard, I took the script from the wizard and found out the differences in the query.

I was using the below code

```
RESTORE LOG DBName_delta FROM DISK='E:\DiffBak1.TRN' WITH NORECOVERY
GO
```

I have changed the code to

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DBrel02t_delta] FROM  DISK = N'E:\DiffBak1.TRN' WITH  FILE = 1,  NORECOVERY,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

This resolved the issue. Use the below query to find out the lsn details of your backup.

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK  = N’<backup file>’;
```

Comment: This means that you have a non-English character in the file path. The `N` prefix means that the string is Unicode. If all characters were English this wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Not exactly. Instead of restoring the log, the second code was restoring the database. That made the difference. I scripted the step and found out the difference.